# How to you move, or scale adjustment layers in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I was sent a document. That looks something like this:

[image]

That orange circle is an adjustment layer

[image]

I can not, for the life of me, figure out how to move and scale an adjustment layer.

The document has more radial gradient adjustment layers. All different sizes and in different places:

[image]

So my question is, how the hell is this done? How do you move and position the gradient adjustment? I've searched the adobe forums and I'm either searching for the wrong term 'position adjustment layers' or there's some voodoo going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those *are not* "adjustment layers".

Those are **Gradient Fill Layers**.
`Layer > New Fill Layer > Gradient`

**Double click** the layer thumbnail and you can adjust the gradient.

[image]

Comment: OMFG! You can just drag them. I was trying to move them without the dialog box open. **puts face in palm**

Comment:  Been there. You can also just drag Layer Styles with that dialog open too.. and pattern layers.. actually I always try dragging to see if it works. It will in many areas.